# CategoryView is not shown

Tags: python, django

CategoryView is not shown.I wrote in views.py like

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Category

    def get_object(self):
        category_name = self.kwargs['category']
        return Category.objects.get(name=category_name)

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = POST
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentCreateForm()
        return context
```

in detail.html

```
<div>
    <p>{{ object.text }}</p>
</div>

          <div>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
              Category
            </a>
                   <div>
                         {% for category in get_object.comment_set.all %}
                            <a href="{% url 'category' category.name %}">
                            {{ category.name }}
                            </a>
                         {% endfor %}
                   </div>
          </div>
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
        path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('category/<str:category>/',views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
    ]
```

But now in detail.html no category data is shown.I really cannot understand why this happens.I think I can get data by using get_object.comment_set.all in template but it is wrong.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my code?
By reading comments, I  rewrote

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Category

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category
        return context
```

but no category is shown.I wanna show all category in Category model.
Furthermore,I wrote

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = POST
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentCreateForm()
        context['category'] = Category
        return context
```

but same thing happens.

Comment: please post your urls.py

Comment: There's nothing in your detail view that mentions categories. You have `get_object.comment_set.all` but you have not set `get_object` in the template context. Did you mean to use `object.comment_set.all` instead? However, that would presumably return comments, so `{% for comment in object.commend_set.all %}` would make more sense.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, it is.I ca understand ur meaning, but how should I fix this?

Comment: @Walucas i added urls.py

Comment: @Alasdair comment??I wanna show category form

Comment: *I wanna show category form* - I'm confused, your question doesn't mention category form anywhere, only `CommentCreateForm`. You say *I think I can get data by using get_object.comment_set.all in template* - what data? Your `get_object` is in an entirely different view, you can't call `CategoryView.get_object` from the template of a different view.

Comment: @Alasdair Sorry,I wanna show CategoryView class not category form. I wanna show `class CategoryView(ListView):`  .I wanna show Category's models data in  `return Category.objects.get(name=category_name) `

Comment: It doesn't make sense to include one view inside another. If you want to display a category or categories in the template, you can add them to the context in `get_context_data`. Note that `Category.objects.get(name=category_name)` will return a single object, but `{% for category in get_object.comment_set.all %}` is trying to loop through a list. Do you want to show a single category or all categories? If you want to show a single category, how do you know which category to show? The detail view does not have `<str:category>` in the URL, only `<int:pk>`.

Comment: @Alasdair I updated my question.If you know something, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your detail view's `get_context_data` method, you can add the list of categories to the context:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Then in your template for the detail view, you can loop through `categories`.

```
<ul>
  {% for category in categories %}
    <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```